# In vert.x web app, how to enable the usage of TLS 1.3 in a web application

Tags: tls1.2, vert.x, tls1.3, tls1.1

In a vert.x web application, does someone know by chance how to add TLS 1.3 and disable all prior versions of TLS used by default(TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2?
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to configure the TLS versions for receiving or sending HTTP-requests.

### Configure TLS versions for Vert.x `HttpServer`

What you are looking for is the [`HttpServerOptions`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/http/HttpServerOptions.html) class. You can provide an instance of that class as a paremeter of `vertx.createHttpServer()`.
The `HttpServerOptions` class has two methods:

- [`serverOptions.addEnabledSecureTransportProtocol()`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/http/HttpServerOptions.html#addEnabledSecureTransportProtocol-java.lang.String-)
- and [`serverOptions.removeEnabledSecureTransportProtocol()`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/http/HttpServerOptions.html#removeEnabledSecureTransportProtocol-java.lang.String-)

that you can use to configure the TLS versions the server uses.
Here is a full example:

```java
final var vertx = Vertx.vertx()

final var serverOptions = new HttpServerOptions();
serverOptions.removeEnabledSecureTransportProtocol("TLSv1");
serverOptions.removeEnabledSecureTransportProtocol("TLSv1.1");
serverOptions.removeEnabledSecureTransportProtocol("TLSv1.2");
serverOptions.addEnabledSecureTransportProtocol("TLSv1.3");

final var server = vertx.createHttpServer(serverOptions);
```

Please have a look at the constant [`TCPSSLOptions.DEFAULT_ENABLED_SECURE_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOLS`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/net/TCPSSLOptions.html#DEFAULT_ENABLED_SECURE_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOLS), that lists the dafault TLS versions used by the Vert.x HTTP server.

Please also note, that the documentation of this constant says:

> SSLv3 is NOT enabled due to POODLE vulnerability http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE

### Configure TLS versions for Vert.x `WebClient`

What you are looking for is the [`WebClientOptions`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/client/WebClientOptions.html) class. You can provide an instance of that class as a paremeter of `WebClient.create()`.
The `WebClientOptions` class has two methods:

- [`clientOptions.addEnabledSecureTransportProtocol()`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/client/WebClientOptions.html#addEnabledSecureTransportProtocol-java.lang.String-)
- and [`clientOptions.removeEnabledSecureTransportProtocol()`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/client/WebClientOptions.html#removeEnabledSecureTransportProtocol-java.lang.String-)

that you can use to configure the TLS versions the server uses.
Here is a full example:

```java
final var vertx = Vertx.vertx();

final var clientOptions = new WebClientOptions();
clientOptions.removeEnabledSecureTransportProtocol("TLSv1");
clientOptions.removeEnabledSecureTransportProtocol("TLSv1.1");
clientOptions.removeEnabledSecureTransportProtocol("TLSv1.2");
clientOptions.addEnabledSecureTransportProtocol("TLSv1.3");

final var client = WebClient.create(vertx, clientOptions);
```

The dafault versions used by the Vert.x `WebClient` are specified using the same constant as in the server.